# R: pairwise Euclidean distance between columns of two matrices

Tags: r, performance, matrix, distance, euclidean-distance

The following loop takes too lonng to run (2mins/iteration)
The tumor_signals is size 950000x422
The normal_signals is size 950000x772
Any ideas for how to speed it up?

```
for(i in 1:ncol(tumor_signals)){
x <- as.vector(tumor_signals[,i])
print("Assigned x")
y <- t((t(normal_signals) - x)^2)
print("assigned y")
y <- t(sqrt(colSums(y)))
print("done")
#all_distance <- cbind(all_distance,matrix(distance))
print(i)
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to be subtracting one column of the tumor signals at a time from the entire normal_signals matrix?  Do you really want to be transposing the large normal_signals matrix 2x every single run?  You could do that once before you start if it's necessary.  Given that the two datasets don't have the same number of columns, or a multiple thereof, what is the euclidean distance really between?

Comment: @Jogn, agreed, I'm confused as to what OP wants. Removing all those print calls would speed it up quite a bit.

Comment: At such a large data structure, `t` is one of the bottle necks, for sure.

Comment: A good point. Yes, t is a bottle neck and thank you all for helping me figure this out.(I am a new programmer , been a few months only). I installed fields package. rdist() works faster . So for processing everything,takes about an 1.5 hour. To answer the question, the output must be ncol(normal_signals) x ncol(tumor_signals), Each column == patient profile and so we need to calculate the distance for each patient to each normal sample available. Sorry for any confusion and thanks alot for help

Comment: distance is between each tumor_signal column and each normal_signal column. I dont think removing print statements speeds up the process. I inserted these to see which step is slowest . Any other ways of checking that ?

Comment: You can use `Rprof` function that was made to profile functions.

Answer (score 7):

There's a bug in your code -- you don't need to take the transpose of `normal_signals`. As I understand it, you are trying to compute, for all `i = 1,2,...422`, and `j=1,2,...,772`, the Euclidean distance between `tumor_signals[,i]` and `normal_signals[,j]`. You would probably want the results in a 422 x 772 matrix. There's a function `rdist()` in the package `fields` that will do this for you:

```
require(fields)
result <- rdist(t(tumor_signals), t(normal_signals))
```

Incidentally, a Google search for `[R Euclidean distance]` would have easily found this package.

Comment: I am trying out this package:

Comment: thanks Prasad, it was a great help. Decomposing the dist function and removing t gives same result at almost the same speed.

Comment: Nowadays. such a search finds this question.